CASE WHEN and PARTITION BY - Order Types per customer
Input Table



Cust ID
Order Type




Cust 1
Online


Cust 2
In-Store


Cust 2
Online


Cust 3
In-Store



Expected Output table



Cust ID
New_Order Type




Cust 1
Online only


Cust 2
Both


Cust 3
In-Store only



Here I have simplified my actual problem. But I would like to know if a customer has both order type or online only or in-store only. Please help with simplest query possible.
I am able to tell if the cust has both order types or just one but not able to tell which one order type, using a case when and partition by cust_id.
I tried something like this. But the other column will be NULL always. I would like to have these 2 in the same line item.
CASE WHEN o_type = 'Online' THEN count(cust_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id, o_type ORDER BY cust_id) END AS count_on,
CASE WHEN o_type = 'In-Store' THEN count(cust_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id, o_type ORDER BY cust_id) END AS count_in


select "Cust ID", case when count(distinct "Order Type") > 1 then 'Both' else min("Order Type") as "Order Type" from T group by "Cust ID"

Your order bys in the expressions you posted were unnecessary (and potentially wrong in other scenarios) by the way.

If you don't want to use the group by because the query is more complicated and you can't' use count(distinct) over then you might say instead: coalesce(case when min(o_type) over (partition by cust_id) <> max(o_type) over (partition by cust_id) then 'Both' end, o_type)

A simple aggregation query should do the trick
Select [Cust ID]
      ,NewVal = case when min([Order Type])<>max([Order Type]) then 'Both' else max([Order Type]) end
from YourTable
Group By [Cust ID]

Results
Cust ID     NewVal
Cust 1      Online
Cust 2      Both
Cust 3      In-Store


Here is a fiddle showing that this solution works https://dbfiddle.uk/5nzlZqZD

Data
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   CustID    VARCHAR(80)  NOT NULL  
  ,OrderType VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable
(CustID,OrderType) VALUES 
('Cust 1','Online'),
('Cust 2','In-Store'),
('Cust 2','Online'),
('Cust 3','In-Store');

use Subquery,IIFand concat
select 
  CustID, 
  iif(
    OrderType2 like '%,%', 
    'Both', 
    concat(OrderType2, ' only') 
  ) NewOrderType
from 
  (
    select 
      CustID, 
      string_agg(OrderType, ',') OrderType2 
    from 
      mytable 
    group by 
      CustID
  ) a

dbfiddle

SELECT
    CustID

    -- it could be better
    , New_OrderType = (
        CASE
            WHEN SUM(IIF(OrderType = 'Online', 1, 0)) > 0 AND SUM(IIF(OrderType = 'In-Store', 1, 0)) > 0 THEN 'Both'
            WHEN SUM(IIF(OrderType = 'Online', 1, 0)) > 0 THEN 'Online only'
            WHEN SUM(IIF(OrderType = 'In-Store', 1, 0)) > 0 THEN 'In-Store only'
            ELSE NULL
        END
    )
FROM CTE
GROUP BY CustID


A good answer includes an explanation
